# Why isn't the walrus operation a valid statement?

Tags: python, terminal, walrus-operator

I was doing some python in a terminal, at a point I wrote `x := 1` and it showed a Syntax Error.

```
>>> x := 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1   
    x := 1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that the walrus operator is an expression, but other expressions work perfectly.

```
>>> 5 + 3 - 1
7
```

Even the walrus operation work inside parentheses.

```
>>> (x := 1)
1
```

So my question is, Why are every other expression valid as a statement, but walrus isn't?

Comment: assignments are not expressions

Comment: Take a look at the [exceptional cases in PEP572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases). It explains this scenario

Comment: Because this is not walrus usage and walrus is discouraged in use of normal assignments. PEP puts it quite nicely. Parentheses are just a way of making walrus context not visible as standalone line.

Comment: @Chris Well, assignment expressions are :) But the grammar specifically prohibits using assignment expressions as expression statements, as explained in the PEP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PEP 572, ["Exceptional cases"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) (emphasis mine):

> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level
> of an expression statement. Example:
>
> ```
> y := f(x)  # INVALID
> (y := f(x))  # Valid, though not recommended
> ```
>
> This
> rule is included to simplify the choice for the user between an
> assignment statement and an assignment expression -- **there is no
> syntactic position where both are valid**.

It was simple to exclude bare assignment expressions in the grammar. It would have been much more complicated to ban only *some* parenthesized expressions (namely, those that contain assignment expressions) while still allowing others, which is why `(y := f(x))` is valid.